# Can't emit from one child to another

Tags: vue.js

I have component, inside it I am doing emiting:

```
methods: {
    sendClick(e)
    {
        bus.$emit('codechange', this.mycode);
        console.log(this.selectedLanguage);
        this.$parent.sendCode();
        this.$parent.changeView();
    }

}
```

In the parent component I am hadling data:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentView: 'past-form',
    mycode: ''
  },
  methods:
  {
    changeView()
    {
        console.log(this.mycode);
    },

    sendCode()
    {
        console.log("Code is sended to server");
        this.currentView = 'view-form';
        bus.$emit('codechange', this.mycode);
    }   

  }, 

  created()
  {         
    bus.$on('codechange', function(mycode){
    console.log("test"); // this works
    this.mycode = mycode; // this works
    }.bind(this));

  }

})
```

Handling in parent work fine. But on clicking on `sendCode()` I want to send data to third component. The third component code:

```
Vue.component('view-form', {
    template: `
        <div class="ViewCodeContainer">
            <div class="ViewCode">my code here</div>
            <code> {{mycode}} </code>
            <div class="ViewCodeMenu">my menu here</div>
        </div>`,
        data() {
            return {
                mycode: ''
            }
        },
    created()
        {       
            bus.$on('codechange', function(mycode){
            console.log("hererere");
                console.log(mycode);
            this.mycode = mycode;
            }.bind(this));
            console.log("test");
        }
})
```

But handling of code does not working. Block `console.log("hererere");` is not executed. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like `view-form` component is not created at all. Make sure it appears somewhere in you template. Or console.log something in `created` hook before listener. Otherwise it should work: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/74/

Comment: Its created because I can switch to it. And if I am hardcode 'mycode' to it i can see it

Comment: Are you using a dynamic component with `is` set to `currentView`?

Comment: Yes, i use dynamic component with `is`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Wostex is correct in this case. Essentially, your `view-form` component doesn't exist when the event is emitted. It doesn't exist until you change the view, which you are doing in the event handler. So there is no way for it to receive the event because your handler doesn't exist.

If your dynamic component is a child of the parent, just pass the code as a property.

```
<component :is="currentView" :mycode="mycode"></component>
```

And update your `view-form` component.

```
Vue.component('view-form', {
  props:["mycode"],
  template: `
    <div class="ViewCodeContainer">
      <div class="ViewCode">my code here</div>
      <code> {{code}} </code>
      <div class="ViewCodeMenu">my menu here</div>
    </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      code: this.mycode
    }
  }
})
```

Here is a working [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/LLxOJQ).